# Are there any good alternatives to Kue for background process management in node?

Tags: node.js, background-process, kue

I'm working on a project where the background processes are increasing exponentially. So I'm looking for a good priority background queue for node.

While looking for it online I found [Kue](http://learnboost.github.com/kue/) but I'm new to this so I'm not sure whether this is the best option.

Comment: Have used Kue... it really good.

Comment: Kue if a good tool. We are using it to manage background processes with long duration.

Comment: it'd be nice if it had user login